# Characterizing a union of intervals.

Tags: measure-theory, cantor-set

Find the measure of the set of real numbers in $(0,1)$ whose binary expansions contains zeroes in the odd positions, such that $x = 0.k_1k_2k_3\ldots$

Checking odd positions one at a time:

If $k_1 = 0, x \in (0,\frac12)$.

If $k_1,k_2 = 0, x \in (0,\frac{1}{8}) \cup (\frac{2}{8},\frac38)$.

If $k_1,k_2,k_3 = 0, x \in (0,\frac{1}{32}) \cup (\frac{2}{32},\frac{3}{32}) \cup (\frac{8}{32},\frac{9}{32}) \cup (\frac{10}{32}.\frac{11}{32})$.

I'm at a loss for characterizing this in a more concise way, akin to the Cantor set, to the union containing all $x$ such that $k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n = 0$.

Comment: Written $x$ in 4-base arithmetics, only digits $0$ and $2$ allowed (as for Cantor set in 3-base arithmetics, only digits $0$ and $2$ allowed). Does that help?

Comment: Would that be...

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{4^k}, a_k \in \{0,2\}$$?

Comment: Yes, precisely. If I read the original statement right. $x=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6\dots_2$ where $a_{2n-1}=0$. We think of $x$ as of $x=0.(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)(a_5a_6)\dots_4$ where $a_1a_2$, $a_3a_4$, $a_5a_6, \dots$ are "digits" themselves, representing actual 4-base digits in binary notation.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, I can apply essentially the same argument as I would on the Cantor set to show that this set has a measure of zero.